# Why does no data showing using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have this exe that have only a manual to what will be create table in ms access but the exe also support connection to mysql, ms sql server, postgre. I used mysql for my database and succesfully inserted and query but one table cannot read the data. but if in ms access it is succesful showing data

Comment: I see you are new so rather than downvoting your question without comment, might I suggest you add a *lot* more information! Anyone hoping to answer this for you will need a lot more to go on!

Comment: the application connect to a database ms access or mysql. The ms access is perfect but the mysql is about 80% working im wondering whats the problem?

Comment: But what is the application, what is it based on, did you write it? You can't just say "why can't I connect to MySQL?" There could be many many reasons. Most likely a connection string issue, or permissions, but since we have no idea what the application is, what or where the database is, how connections are managed etc etc we can't answer a blind question!

Comment: When i used the ms access as the database all data is showing in the program application. but when i used the mysql database the same exact scenario there is some data not showing?

Comment: I have succesfully inserting data in mysql using a third party program means that the table is ok but when the querying the table wont show other data in the third party program. but it is showing when i use ms access

Comment: please provide the code you used for connections to the database, and check if you can actually connect to the sql db from local machine by using any db workbench

Comment: I dont have the code its compiled. just a manual in ms access what table to be created. but supports connection in mysql i have success inserting and querying data using mysql but some data not showing but when is used ms access all data is showing?  All is local in my laptop